# Opposite of push();

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

What is the opposite of the JavaScript `push();` method?

Say I had an array:

```
var exampleArray = ['remove'];
```

I want to `push();` the word `'keep'` -

```
exampleArray.push('keep');
```

How do I delete the string `'remove'` from the array?

Comment: You can find a list if all array methods in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: First, find the index of the element you want to remove:

`var array = [2, 5, 9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);`
Note: browser support for indexOf is limited; it is not supported in Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

Then remove it with splice:

`if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array

Comment: var exampleArray = ['myName'];
exampleArray.push('hi');
console.log(exampleArray);

exampleArray.pop();
console.log(exampleArray);

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Well, you've kind of asked two questions. The opposite of `push()` (as the question is titled) is `pop()`.

```js
var exampleArray = ['myName'];
exampleArray.push('hi');
console.log(exampleArray);

exampleArray.pop();
console.log(exampleArray);
```

`pop()` will remove the last element from `exampleArray` and return that element ("hi") but it will not delete the string "myName" from the array because "myName" is not the last element.

What you need is [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) or [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
var exampleArray = ['myName'];
exampleArray.push('hi');
console.log(exampleArray);

exampleArray.shift();
console.log(exampleArray);
```

```js
var exampleArray = ['myName'];
exampleArray.push('hi');
console.log(exampleArray);

exampleArray.splice(0, 1);
console.log(exampleArray);
```

For more array methods, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Mutator_methods

Comment: @jasonscript: For the record, I never suggested `pop()` does NOT remove the last element from an array. Just that it wouldn't remove the first element `myName` in the array `['myName', 'hi']`, which is what @AlexSafayan wants to do.

Answer (score 165):

`push()` adds at end; `pop()` deletes from end.

`unshift()` adds to front; `shift()` deletes from front.

`splice()` can do whatever it wants, wherever it wants.